# How to block Referrer Spam

Tags: nginx, spam-prevention

I am using NGINX and one of my site is suffering from referrer spam.

I followed the NGINX wiki, and I found [this](http://wiki.nginx.org/Referrer_Spam_Blocking) but after using the code, it is blocking my site. Is there any solution? I have also tried using this code but it didn't worked

```
if ($http_referer ~ "spamdomain1\.com|spamdomain2\.com|spamdomain3\.com")  { 
return 444;
}
```

I want to block the domain from where I am getting referrer hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a map.

```
# at the http level:
map $http_referer $drop_referer {
    default 0;
    ~spamdomain1\.com   1;
    ~spamdomain2\.com   1;
    ~spamdomain3\.com   1;
    # ... (put these in an included file if there are many)
}

# in your server stanza:
if ($drop_referer) {
    return 444;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We began working on our internal tool [ReferrerSpamBot](http://referrerspambot.icenodes.com/) that helps adding the dynamic filters to your Google Analytics account and also we want to develop a module for nginx in the future. Check out the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/bmustata/referrer-spam-bot)

Comment: I will be waiting for nginx module. However, I can manually remove that spam sites from Google Analytics but this is not what I am looking for.